# Can pronouns be in a state of?

Tags: american-english

I have a question on the following sentence: "After this meeting, the team is in understanding of the plan"

Specifically, could you say someone is in understanding of something?

Comment: What does your research lead you believe? Have you searched Google books for "understanding of"? When you look up the word "understanding" in several dictionaries, what data did you find?

Comment: i googled "in understanding of" and nothing relevant showed up they all say you can "understand in" something. perhaps if you understand in something then you are in understanding of something? But i think "understand in" is quite different than "in understanding of" as the latter emphases the state of being in of understanding. Not sure if it's correct way of saying (english isnt my first language)

Comment: It's by far more natural to say: *the team understands the plan*. It's probably not ungrammatical, per se, to say *in understanding of*, but since no native speaker I know of actually says that, then that ipso facto makes it ungrammatical, practically speaking.

Comment: *Understanding of* usually follows a possessive pronoun, such as *one's understanding of the plan*, *the team's understanding of the plan*, *her understanding of the plan*, *someone's unerstanding of the plan*... but I wouldn't substitute *to be in understanding* in any of those phrases.

Comment: My understanding of your question leads me to say that it is not idiomatic in English.

Comment: I am in understanding of your question, but while I don't think what I just said is strictly ungrammatical,... it's absolutely not idiomatic either.

Comment: The title seems a little confusing. You're asking about neither pronouns nor the expression "in a state of".

Comment: Ok, here goes: No, one (native speaker) would say say that "someone is  in the understanding of". One would say: It is my understanding that [whatever].

Comment: The [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+understanding+of%2C+having+an+understanding&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20understanding%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chaving%20an%20understanding%3B%2Cc0) actually favours 'in understanding of' over 'having an understanding'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguably, no.

The OED does not record this usage of *understanding*. Also, searching for *am/are/is in understanding of* results in no hits either on google books or on the internet at large.

Possible fixes include

*the team understands the plan*
*the team developed/reached/achieved an understanding of the plan*

and many others. However,

*the team is in the state of understanding of the plan*,

while grammatical, would not be used under normal circumstances.

Comment: Sorry, but the OED is not relevant here for usage.

Comment: @Lambie Why so ?

Comment: @Nigel J Let me see if I can answer that....well, the simple answer is that the OED is not a grammar book. And this is more of a grammar question than a word meaning question.

Comment: @Lambie But isn't what's at issue here precisely a lexical question, rather than a grammar question? Namely, isn't the issue whether the noun *understanding* has a meaning that includes, roughly, 'a state of understanding'?

Comment: @linguisticturn No, I don't think it is. As you yourself say, it isn't grammtical. :)